# std::find does not find free operator==

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following structs definied in my Project:

```cpp
// Condition.h
struct Condition {
    std::string key{};
    std::string value{};
}
```

```cpp
//Metadata.h
struct Metadata {
   std::string key{};
   std::string value{};
   std::string other{};
}
```

Then i have defined a `check` Function in another `.h/.cpp` files like this:

```cpp
// Checker.h
namespace util {
    bool operator==(const Metadata& metadata_element, const Condition& condition);
    bool operator!=(const Metadata& metadata_element, const Condition& condition);
    bool operator==(const Condition& condition, const Metadata& metadata_element);
    bool operator!=(const Condition& condition, const Metadata& metadata_element);
    bool check(const Condition& condition, const std::vector<Metadata>& metadata);
}
```

```cpp
//Checker.cpp 
namespace util {
    bool operator==(const Metadata& metadata_element, const Condition& condition) {
      return metadata_element.key == condition.condition && metadata_element.value == condition.value;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Metadata& metadata_element, const Condition& condition) {
      return !(metadata_element == condition);
    }

    bool operator==(const Condition& condition, const Metadata& metadata_element) {
      return metadata_element == condition;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Condition& condition, const Metadata& metadata_element) {
      return !(condition == metadata_element);
    }

    bool check(const Condition& condition, const std::vector<Metadata>& metadata) {
      return std::find(metadata.begin(), metadata.end(), condition) != metadata.end(); // gives me an error
    }
}
```

Doing something like `condition == metadata[0]` works.
But if i add the `std::find` call i got the following error:

```
error C2676: binary '==' : 'const Metadata' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

I also tried to copy the code to some new project and there it works without any trouble which i found a little bit strange.

**EDIT:**

The Problem seems to be because the Operators are in an different Namespace then the two Structs.

Comment: Your structs are called Metadata and Condition, but your operators are defined on MetadataElement and TransformCondition...? Could you show an actual [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @codeling sorry for that i edit the question so that the types are now the right ones

Comment: Are the comparison operators declared in the header file, too? The point is to make them visible at the call site.

Comment: @alagner i was trying this as well but the error is the same

Comment: @Kevin are you sure? I've managed to [reproduce it](https://godbolt.org/z/9j4Gqcvbc) and the problem seems operator visibility.

Comment: @alagner i just checked again (also do a complete rebuild) with the function definitions of the `operator==` inside the `checker.h` but i got the same error. Strange thing is that i can compare single elements of that types without an error

Comment: @Kevin I wonder if your project setup isn't messed up somehow. Anyway, can you just you `find_if`+lambda as a workaround? (not that it were a good solution in long term...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241710/discussion-between-kevin-and-alagner).

Answer (score 1):

The usual practice is to declare the operators (`==`, `!=`, etc.) in the same header as the types they operate on, as the operators are part of the interface:

```cpp
// condition.h
struct Condition {
    // (...)
}

bool operator==(const Condition & lhs, const Condition& rhs) {
    // (...)
}
```

If you have good reasons to place those declarations in separate headers, just make sure that each source file that uses the operators (like the place where you call `std::find`) includes also the header with operators:

```cpp
// condition.h
struct Condition {
    // (...)
}
```

```cpp
// condition_eq.h
#include "condition.h"

bool operator==(const Condition & lhs, const Condition& rhs) {
    // (...)
}
```

```cpp
// find.cpp
#include "condition.h"
#include "condition_eq.h"

// some code that uses the operator ==
```

Comment: I'd probably declare those operators inside the class as friends to speed up compilation times and take advantage of the ADL should they be part of the interface.